# pycharm ide doesn't open file in editor in guest linux virtual machine over vmm and vnc

Tags: pycharm, qemu, kvm

pycharm doesn't work fine on vmm (qemu kvm) over VNC client. I can't open pycharm editor when clicking on file to open in pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

change default video adapter for your VM from Cirrus to QXL